# Create add on for View Menu

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Can you add an add-on to the view menu, instead of the object menu?

```
def register():
  bpy.utils.register_class(MyAddOn)
  bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func) 
 # Adds to the Object menu
```

My guess it's something to do with the register function, but I can't find any options for this - the API came up with nothing

Comment: If you enable python tooltips, you can hover over menus and it will show their type. You must disable auto-opening of menus or whatever the option is called when you hover over them for it to work though. it is `VIEW3D_MT_view`

Comment: @Gorgious -- is there any document that lists these?  E.g., Object Data Properties

Comment: @Gorgious Done! That makes it a lot easier. Is there a way to copy the tooltip snippet to the clipboard?